# do the warring parties in the Mahabharata divide approximately into Siva and Vishnu devotees?

Tags: mahabharata, symbols

There are exceptions of course - Bhishma recognized Krishna as Parabrahman and Amba(Shikhandi) got the boon of being able to kill Bhishma from Siva.

As far as I can tell Shikhandi is the only Siva devotee who fought for the Pandavas (Arjuna worships Siva to get the Pashupatastra but obviously his primary Aradhya was Krishna)

Siva helped Aswatthama carry out the night slaughter in the Pandava camp.  Aswatthama himself is considered a partial Avatara of Siva, if I am not mistaken.

Another huge exception is the Narayani Sena - who were given to Duryodhana by Krishna.

But the portrayals of the war on TV serials show it largely as a war between sacred ash wearers and wearers of the Vaishnavite Namam.

Was this approximately correct?

Comment: i'm confident those who rejected Krishna's advice would also reject Brahma's or Shiva's advice. and TV serial portrayals are opinion based mega serial type drama. They are aptly nicknamed *MegaBharat* instead of MahaBharat

Comment: Which devasur war is not? Shiva and Brahma are dear to Asuras, because they don't see profile or long term intention of their bhakt. Unlike Vishnu on whose head the balancing task comes at. So asuras always find at loggerheads with Vishnu. (Although many asuras were killed by Shiva, Durga et al who are non-Vishnu)